# nav2_util - no such file or directory tf2_geometry_msgs

Tags: ros, nav-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have observed during building the Navigation2 from source on new PC (with ROS Galactic, Ubuntu 20.04) that the `nav2_util` package won't build correctly:

```
...
Finished <<< nav2_simple_commander [0.69s]
--- stderr: nav2_util
In file included from /home/piotr/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_util/src/costmap.cpp:19:
/home/piotr/nav2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_util/include/nav2_util/geometry_utils.hpp:24:10: fatal error: tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.hpp: No such file or directory
24 | #include "tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.hpp"
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/nav2_util_core.dir/build.make:76: src/CMakeFiles/nav2_util_core.dir/costmap.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:212: src/CMakeFiles/nav2_util_core.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
---
Failed <<< nav2_util [8.28s, exited with code 2]Summary: 6 packages finished [31.9s]
1 package failed: nav2_util
1 package had stderr output: nav2_util
27 packages not processed
```

I followed these steps:

```
mkdir -p ~/nav2_ws/src
cd ~/nav2_ws/src
git clone https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2.git --branch galactic
cd ~/nav2_ws
rosdep install -y -r -q --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro galactic
colcon build --symlink-install
```

It seems only after installing additionally (next to rosdep):

`sudo apt-get install ros-galactic-nav-2d-msgs ros-galactic-nav-msgs`

Nav2 packages can build correctly.

I have searched a bit after this problem but I didn't find this as a solution suggestion. I am not sure it is even the correct approach too...

What could be the source of this problem? Any suggestions/better fixes/explanations are welcome.

Best,

Łukasz Janiec

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/396138/nav2_util---no-such-file-or-directory-tf2_geometry_msgs/) by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3064 on 2022-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not exactly sure why you're seeing that. I might recommend try a new terminal, sourcing `/opt/ros/galactic/setup.bash` and rebuilding after deleting your install / build spaces in case there's some odd caching going on.

I just cloned the galactic branch in my `/tmp` directory and confirmed that `nav2_util` is building fine and the binaries are also tuning over in CI.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2022-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-02-14**:
It must have been this odd thing with cache because I can't reproduce it now with rebuilding everything again (even after removing `ros-galactic-nav-2d-msgs`, `ros-galactic-nav-msgs`) and sourcing everything by hand in known sequence. At least Google will lead people with the same (rare?) problem to this question.